# Belongsto with condition - laravel 4

Tags: php, database, laravel, orm, eager-loading

I have 2 tables

1. Album

   `id |isactive| name`
2. Gallery

   `id |album_id| is_cover`

One `Album` may have multiple `Gallery`

I need to pull the cover photo of each album which is active

```
class Gallery extends \Eloquent {

 public function Album() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Album')->where("is_active","=","Y");
    }
    // Add your validation rules here
    public static $rules = []

    // Don't forget to fill this array
    protected $fillable = []
}
```

my ORM is as below

```
Gallery::with('Album')->where('is_cover','=','Y')
```

Since i have already appended `is_active='Y'` on model but still it is showing all albums(i mean inactive albums are also showing)

Comment: It seems that you pasted just a bit of the code, and that bit is 100% correct. Check and paste the queries that was executed (use `DB::getQueryLog()`)